# Increment a byte by one as if it were a Base10 number

Tags: c

I'm reading data from a serial port from a hardware device which I need to increment by 1 and then send back out to the device however, I need to increment it as if it were a base10 number.

For example, if I read 0x09, I need to send back 0x10 rather than 0x0a.  Or, if I receive 0x89, I should send back 0x90.  If I receive 0x99, I send back 0x00 and carry the 1 up to the previous byte.  It's actually a total of 5 bytes I have to run through.

I have this increment working in the following way.  I'd like know know if there's a better way through some unique shifting and/or and/or'ing of bits.

Thank you for any pointers you can provide!

Stateful

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  //start with 0x09 as byte
  char input = 0x09;
  printf("input is: 0x%02x\n", input);

  //increment it by one
  input++;

  //turn it into a two char array as a base10 value, ignore overflow for now
  char asString[3];
  sprintf(asString, "%d", input);

  //convert back to byte
  unsigned char newI = ((asString[0]-0x30)*16)+((asString[1]-0x30));
  printf ("newI is 0x%02x\n", newI);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like BCD — [binary coded decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) — arithmetic.

Comment: Your conversion back to char looks fine to me but consider what `input++;` will do if you receive 0x99.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You compute the modulo 16 of the received number.
If it's 9, you add 7, else 1.

Comment: Unless the number is 0x99, in which case you set it to 0 and propagate the carry.

Comment: This worked wonderfully, thank you.  I got it worked out to carry the 1 up through all five bytes if 0x99 is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the whole byte sequence from BCD to an integer type, add, then convert back.  Something like these functions should work for the conversion, but be aware that you may need a longer type than `unsigned` if you need to support completely arbitrary 5-byte BCD sequences (but 5 bytes of BCD suspiciously coincides with the range of a 32-bit integer).

```
/*
 * Decodes a BCD byte sequence to an unsigned integer.  The bytes are assumed to be in
 * order from most- to least-significant.
 */
unsigned bcd_to_int(unsigned char bytes[], int byte_count) {
    unsigned result = 0;
    int counter;

    for (counter = 0; counter < byte_count; counter += 1) {
        result = result * 100 + (bytes[counter] & 0xf0) * 10 + (bytes[counter] & 0x0f);
    }

    return result;
}

/*
 * Encodes an unsigned integer into a BCD byte sequence.  The bytes will be ordered
 * from most- to least-significant.
 */
void int_to_bcd(unsigned char bytes[], int byte_count, unsigned value) {
    int counter;

    for (counter = byte_count; counter-- > 0; ) {
        unsigned chunk = value % 100;

        bytes[counter] = (chunk / 10) * 0x10 + (chunk % 10);
        value /= 100;
    }
}
```

You could also implement long-form addition directly on your byte sequence; that might perform as well or better, but if you want to perform more or different operations than a single add / increment then it will be to your advantage to use native arithmetic.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, I think there's a shift operation missing when isolating the high four bits. Shouldn't this (bytes[counter] & 0xf0) be changed to ((bytes[counter] & 0xf0)>>4)?